# C# xaml image not showing up in application

Tags: c#, image, xaml

When I try to display some smaller (72x72) images in my xaml file as a 20x20 image, they work fine, but when I try to use one that's 96x96, they just don't show up. Here is the code:

```
<Image Source="/Images.Toolbox;component/Images/defaultIcon.jpg" Height="20" Width="20" Stretch="None"/>
```

This is how it looks like with the 72x72, how I want it to look.

[image]

And this is how it looks when I try to use my 96x96 image.

[image]

The working one is a .ico, .png also works. The nonworking one is a .jpg, but this shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: what is deafault image size of picture

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Visual Studio > Solution Explorer
- right-click on the image file > Properties
- make sure the **Build Action** is set to **Resource**.

Comment: same issue unfortunately. I also tried Stretch="fill" but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Is the .jpg in the same location as the "working" icon? (only the filename is different?)

Comment: Yeah. I also tried to make it 96x96 but it's still just a bigger blank space, no image.

Comment: when you click on the image in VS, what do you see in the Properties window -> Build action?  It should be Resource.

Comment: that was it! It wasn't set to Resource. Want to edit your answer and then I'll accept it? thanks.

Comment: Right click the file in the Solution Explorer, not the image on the designer.